# How to start composer-rest-server as background process?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to start composer-rest-server in background using following command :

- composer-rest-server &

Its getting started as background process, but then process is getting stuck after displaying "hyperledger-Composer" banner as :

[image]

Is there anyway we can start composer-rest-server as background process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run it with no arguments it will prompt for arguments (reading from the keyboard). You should launch it with arguments. If you run it with no arguments from a terminal, answering all the questions, at the end it will print the command line you can use to launch it with the answers suppplied using command line arguments.

You should be able to use that command line with `nohup` or `screen` or similar.

Comment: It mean, I need to provide all input as single command then only i can start composer-rest-server as background process?

Comment: Yes, all the arguments must be provided, otherwise the process will attempt to read from the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Run command like this:

```
nohup composer-rest-server -c <network card name> -n never -w true > rest-server.out 2> rest-server.err < /dev/null &
```

all standard output will be saved in `rest-server.out` and errors in rest-server.err

`&` at the end will put it in background and you will get PID

Next time you connect to server and if you want to kill earlier instance then use `ps -A | grep "node"` command to get PID.